# Is there any performance benefits that come with using subroutine in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl 5 and so far I  understand that subroutines are good for code reuse and breaking long procedural scripts into shorter and readable fragments. What I wanted to know is that are there any performance benefits that come with using subroutines? Do they make the code to execute faster?

Take a look at the following snippets;

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
print "Who is the fastest?\n";
```

compared to this one;

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

# defining subroutine 
sub speed_test { 
   print "Who is the fastest?\n"; 
} 

# calling subroutine ; 
speed_test();
```

Comment: Yes. The performance bonuses of Perl programmers that use subroutines is larger than the bonuses of the ones that don't.

Comment: Doing X plus a sub call can't be faster than doing just X.

Comment: A subroutine call in Perl is a bit expensive, compared with C, to start with.  So right there you lose. The code executes in a different place in memory (than when run from main) but I can't think of how that could be used as advantage, while overheads in setting and managing pointers and addresses are well known.   Even if you could come up with an advantage of forcing some code on the stack it would have to beat all the overhead.  And this would be a rare use case, if it existed.

Comment: Advantage of subroutine is in re-usability but not in performance.

Comment: And readability and maintainability and scoping, etc, etc, etc. And thus higher reliability and shorter development and maintenance times. And thus less down time. And thus ... The number of benefits is innumerable. But performance is not one of them.

Answer (score 6):

The performance benefit of subroutines is that, used proficiently, they allow developers to write, test, and release code faster.

The resulting code does not run faster, but that's OK, because it's not the 1960s any more.  These days, hardware is cheap and programmers are expensive.  Hiring a second programmer to speed up slow code production costs orders of magnitude more than buying a second machine (or a higher-powered machine) to speed up slow code execution.

Also, as I note with just about every "how can I micro-optimize Perl code?" question, Perl is not a high-performance language, period.  Never has been, almost certainly never will be.  That's not what it's designed for.  Perl is optimized for speed of development, not speed of execution.

If saving a microsecond here and a microsecond there actually matters to your use case (which it almost certainly doesn't), then you will get *far* greater speed benefits by switching to a lower-level, higher-performance language than you will get by anything you might do differently in Perl.

Answer (score 4):

There is no performance benefit in using subroutines. Actually there is a performance penalty for using them. That is why in highly speed-optimized code subroutines are sometimes "inlined".

But the root of all evil in software development is premature code optimization. Writing code that does not use subroutines/methods to delegate different tasks is way worse on the long run.

Any code block that exceeds 10 (or maybe 25? or 50?) lines usually has to be split. The limit depends on the people you ask.

Comment: *There is no performance benefit in using subroutines.* I believe in this generality this is a questionable statement. There are many effects that determine execution speed. A classical example is cache locality of instructions and data. If these are improved by subroutines, then code may run faster with them. It is hard to make statements when this might have an effect without knowing the internals of the particular interpreter or compiler. I recommend: *only if* you have identified subroutines as a bottle-neck, instrument and measure. Otherwise don't bother. Write readable code.

Comment: @Jens We are talking about perl here - so I would be willing to bet quite an amount on that.

Comment: I understand that, but you made a general statement. One could come up with examples of perl code where you might lose quite an amount :-) In other words, be cautious because *all general statements are false*, including this one :-)